# Why my uploaded IPA binary does not appear on testflight?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ipa

This is the first time I uploaded binary for this project.

The first time I upload, the Transporter inform me that there's no app with that kind of bundle identifier found on my organization's apple developer team. Then I remembered that I do haven't created the app. So I did.

After that, I reupload again. This time, the Transporter successfully uploaded the binary, and also correctly identify the organization too.

But the problem is, I cannot see the build on TestFlight, hours after I uploaded it.

When I tried to reupload the same binary, the Transporter reject it, saying that binary with same version and build number already exist, which means the IPA is actually on the server.

But why I can't see it on my build? Both on preparing app for submission, and testflight, all don't display any build (empty).

Because this is a new app entry, I might miss some steps necessary to at least let it shows on TestFlight. How can I configure this correctly? At the moment I haven't set anything at all to the app submission screen. All I did is create the app, set the app bundle at creating time, and invite some developers to the team. I just want it to show at TestFlight at the moment so my fellow coworkers can help test it.

Comment: Hi, sometimes binary processing fails. If this happen you'll get an email. It says : Invalid binary. Also, sometimes binary processing stuck. No email, no binary. I suggest to re-upload your archive.